# PHP: Is it a good idea to add quotes to all $_GET & $_POST?

Tags: php

In Wordpress, I notice they have a function called `wp_magic_quotes()` ([docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_magic_quotes)).

Here's an example:

```
// If already slashed, strip.
if ( get_magic_quotes_gpc() ) {
    $_GET    = stripslashes_deep( $_GET    );
    $_POST   = stripslashes_deep( $_POST   );
    $_COOKIE = stripslashes_deep( $_COOKIE );
}

// Escape with wpdb.
$_GET    = add_magic_quotes( $_GET    );
$_POST   = add_magic_quotes( $_POST   );
$_COOKIE = add_magic_quotes( $_COOKIE );
$_SERVER = add_magic_quotes( $_SERVER );
```

In my own code (separate from Wordpress), is there any benefit to doing this? Any security benefits?

Perhaps Wordpress do this because their software is used on so many environments they need to make them consistent.

My software is on a single environment and I'm using a PDO connection for my database which is already escaping data.

I'm just trying to work out if there's any benefit to doing this sort of thing.

Comment: based on wordpress security history, i wouldn't imagine it's too useful...

Comment: automatically doing anything to a global variable is a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magic quotes on global variables are typically lazy security and cause worse problems down the road.  I would guess that WordPress added them because they don't trust plugin writers to do proper sanitation of input; or they have a lot of legacy code that expects magic_quotes to be turned on.

The proper way to handle input from the global arrays that come from the user is to filter each one specifically as tightly as possible.  So, if you have:

```
<select name="number">
  <option value="1">Thing 1</option>
  <option value="2">Thing 2</option>
  <option value="3">Thing 3</option>
</select>
```

You should filter it to just be integers between 1 and 3.

```
$_SAFE = array();
$_SAFE['number'] = filter_var($_POST['number'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
if($_SAFE['number'] < 1 || $_SAFE['number'] > 3)
{
  //user is doing something evil, block them, and die.
}
```

Then, sanitize each use for the possible injections, in case you missed something earlier.  For SQL that mean prepared statements passing all variables as typed parameters using PDO or MySQLi. For output to a browser that means htmlentities().

Answer (score 1):

Magic quotes were removed as of PHP 5.4.0. http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php explains why and recommends altneratives such as mysql_real_escape_string. Sanitizing your input is a great idea so long as it's done correctly. Good luck!

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string is also deprecated as being unsafe.  Current best practices are to use prepared statements (some argue prepared statements that only call stored procedures).